# DOM for GetElementsByName for-loop

Tags: javascript, loops, dom, getelementsbyname

I have a small "problem".  I try to do a Loop-for for a
`"getElementsByName"` for each rows in the table.

I try to loop a few values. 
Price * Quantity * discount * tax (select.options) = MY Final price after discout.

**AD: (You have to open Full View)**

For a single line it works great by `getElementById`. However, the need for the creation of the next line (`Button` `Add Position`). So i chose `GetElementsByName`

Also counted for him the value (in place "after rebate")

--EDIT--

I made a loop "For". 
In html code I have a lot the same fields "named" (ex. cena, ile, rabat etc.)
So if I will had 3 rows with this fields I want to calculate for each line separately. But my loop doesn't work.

Full View you can see here:
http://codepen.io/warhero/pen/WwvLZE **(121 line JS)**

My JS code:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('kwotarabat').length; i++) {
  var cena = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('cena')[i].value);
  var ile = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('ile')[i].value);
  var rabat = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('rabat')[i].value);
  var vat = document.getElementsByName('vat')[i].options[document.getElementsByName('vat')[i].selectedIndex].value;
  // vat value
  var wynik = (ile * cena * vat);
  // the net value
  var wynik2 = cena * ile;
  // net amount after discount
  var wynikRabat = (wynik2 * (rabat / 100));
  // gross amount after discount
  var wynikRabatVat = (wynik * (rabat / 100));
  // net amount after discount (display for customers)
  var wynikNetto = (wynik2 - wynikRabat);
  document.getElementsByName('kwotarabat')[i].innerHTML = (wynik + wynik2 - wynikRabat - wynikRabatVat).toFixed(2);
}
```

In Here >> http://codepen.io/warhero/pen/ONVEmZ 
is the code for a single row and calculations are correct.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: did you forget to specify what the "small problem" is?

Comment: Kevin B - sorry for that - now is correct.

Comment: Try using the increment operator `var row =+ '<tr class="none" id="wiersz-' =+ liczba =+ '"><td class="rownum text-center middle">' =+ liczba =+ '</td>' =+ f2 =+ f3 =+ f4 =+ f5 =+ f6 =+ f7 =+ f8 =+ f9 =+ f1 =+ '</tr>';`  `a =+`

Comment: zer00ne thx for answer but it's not what I ased. I Asked about Loop - For. You Try give a `row`. I have set this in first lines my js. 

Here i count values and display it. but my Loop don't work. 
Where I made a mistake?

Comment: Anyone ? I need this but it does not work.. and I don't know how to fix it